# how to find out iowait per process on linux with top command

Tags: linux, io, top

How to find `iowait` to process  on linux with top command?

I want to find out how much time my process wait for i/o.

Comment: you have got to use  `iotop`

Answer (score 12):

If you need to monitor processes in realtime, use `iotop` instead.

`top` can show total amount of iowait of all processes in `wa` parameter:

> wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion

In addition with `top` you can see *load average* that show average number of running + waiting threads. This metric can indirectly indicate disk problems

Comment: Is the WA measured in percentages and updated in real time?

Comment: @fsefs, yes it is. From man pages: `As a default, percentages for these individual categories are displayed.`